# Unable to use graql on commandline

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

So I am using grakn core 1.5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to use graql command.With older versions of grakn it was quite good to have a graql executable available.Here is the command i am using from inside my grakn folder.

```
graql console --keyspace prec --file ./schema.gql
```

However in newer versions on and after 1.5.7,I cannot find the same.

I had a look on the bugs section of grakn and i found [this](https://github.com/graknlabs/biograkn/pull/39) to be close but not much related issue. Following which i tried replacing graql to grakn but now i am getting this error

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: session.SessionService/open
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:233)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:214)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:139)
    at grakn.protocol.session.SessionServiceGrpc$SessionServiceBlockingStub.open(SessionServiceGrpc.java:273)
    at grakn.client.GraknClient$Session.<init>(GraknClient.java:165)
    at grakn.client.GraknClient$Session.<init>(GraknClient.java:136)
    at grakn.client.GraknClient.session(GraknClient.java:123)
    at grakn.core.console.ConsoleSession.<init>(ConsoleSession.java:90)
    at grakn.core.console.GraknConsole.run(GraknConsole.java:99)
    at grakn.core.console.GraknConsole.main(GraknConsole.java:140)
```

Cannot understand what is the resolution for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Thanks to help by grakn team , I resolved the issue by doing the following steps:

1. replace graql with grakn (for versions 1.5 and above)
2. stop grakn server by `./grakn server stop`
3. run `jps` on commandline to identify if there are any processes still running for the grakn server
4. use the process id from step 3 and kill those processes by kill -9
5. Now do `grakn server start`
6. now run your grakn console commands, they will work.

Answer (score 0):

As of Grakn Core 1.5.0, the `graql console` command has been removed in favor of a combined command: `grakn console -k mykeyspace...`

Comment: So I made those changes suggested, and now i am getting this error 

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: session.SessionService/open
 
```
The traceback is mentioned in the question itself. I am not understanding that, how to resolve that error.

Comment: I think i should have rephrased the question. After using grakn console ... I am getting ``` io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found:... ```

Comment: You're using the same `./grakn console` command from the place you launched your sever from using `/grakn server start`?